# ReadyAPI - How to filter by testStep name in TestRunListener.afterStep event handler Target

Tags: groovy, ready-api

I'm trying to add a filter for the TestRunListener.afterSetp event handler. I want to filter it by the current testStep name. Let's say, testStep.Name.contains("XXX").

How can I get the current testStep name in the Target Column?

**context.getCurrentStep().getLabel()** doesn't work

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [official documentation](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/testing/handling-events.html#filter):

> Enter `RegexRequest.*` so that the event is applied only to test items that start with **RegexRequest**.

So in your case you could use `.*XXX.*`.